# sending an email in PHP with information taken from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I want to pull an email from the database as the recipient. If I replace the line `"SELECT student_user_email FROM students";'` with an actual email address I get the desired outcome. However it would be handier to pull a particular email address from the 'students' table. Below is the current code. Wondering if anyone can help?

```
mail('"SELECT student_user_email FROM students";','Sample Form',$msg, 'From: johnsmith@gmail.com');
```

Comment: your query is not running, use mysql_query and mysql_fetch to get a result.

Comment: @dhidy [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

First, use mysqli or PDO because the `mysql_` functions are depricated. The documentation has very useful information to get started with it.

mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

pdo: https://www.php.net/pdo

mail: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

This is what you need to do to connect to your database (from the php documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Once connected you can query the database:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT student_user_email FROM students");

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    if (isset($row->student_user_email)) {
        mail($row->student_user_email,'Sample Form',$msg, 'johnsmith@gmail.com');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send email to a multiple recipients in this way. Because query return array list so you must be looping and send email one by one recipients by this following way,

Try this will work:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "uname", "password");
    if (!$con){
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db("database",$con);
    $sql = "SELECT student_user_email FROM students";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql,$con);

    while ($row_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        // Then you will set your variables for the e-mail using the data 
        // from the array.

        $from = 'you@yoursite.com';
        $to = $row_data['email']; // The column where your e-mail was stored.
        $subject = 'Sample Form';
        $msg = 'Hello world!';
        mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
    }
?>
```

Comment: don't forget the $subject variable in the call to mail - mail($to,$sbj,$msg,$from)